# Factoring out the expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm sorry, it must pretty basic, but...

How to factor out this expression $x^2 + 5x - 5 = 0$  ?

(The method I normally use to factor expressions doesn't work there because when we factor expression above so that format will be $(ax + b)(qx + c)$ $b$ and $c$ definitely won't be integers, and method that I use only works when $b$ and $c$ **are** integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x^2+5x-5$ is a monic polynomial whose roots are $\frac{1}{2} \left(-5+3\sqrt{5}\right)$ and $\frac{1}{2} \left(-5-3\sqrt{5}\right)$,$$x^2+5x-5=\left(x-\frac{1}{2} \left(-5+3\sqrt{5}\right)\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{2} \left(-5-3\sqrt{5}\right)\right).$$

Comment: Just one more question, are roots normally found using computers? Or is it possible to do it algebraically? (For example the polynomial that I provided in the problem)

Comment: All I did was to apply the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) (by hand).

Answer (score 2):

Complete the square:

$(x+5/2)^2 -25/4 -20/4=$

$(x+5/2)^2-45/4=$

$((x+5/2) -\sqrt{45/4})×$

$((x+5/2) +\sqrt{45/4})=$

$(x+5/2 -(3/2)√5)×$

$(x+5/2+(3/2)√5)=$

$(x -a)(x-b)$, with

$a=-5/2 +(3/2)√5$, and $b=-5/2 -(3/2)√5$;

Answer (score 0):

You can use completing square method to factorize it. 
Look at: 
$$x^2+5x-5=x^2+ 2x\times\frac{5}{2}+\frac{25}{4}-\frac{25}{4}-5=(x +\frac{5}{2})^2-(\sqrt\frac{45}{2})^2$$

Now use the fact that $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$, so:
$$x^2+ 5x -5 =(x +\frac{5}{2})^2-(\sqrt\frac{45}{2})^2 = (x+\frac{5}{2}+\sqrt\frac{45}{2})(x+\frac{5}{2}-\sqrt\frac{45}2)$$
which is your answer.

Comment: Use LaTeX please.